# How can I make a nested table fill its outer cell in a JEditorPane

Tags: java, html, css, swing, jeditorpane

I have a grid of tables that consists of an outer table that has two columns and n rows where each cell is in turn filled with a table.  Currently, I have each inner table in a div with some padding, and the inner tables have css to apply borders and background colours.
This gives me a layout where my tables display in a grid with nicely spaced gaps inbetween them.  The only problem I'm having is that I'd like each table to to fill all the available hight in the cell in which it resides.  Currently, they fill the width horizontally but vertically are only as big as they need to be to contain their content.  This gives me uneven vertical gaps between the tables which doesn't look nice.  The CSS for the inner and outer tables and the div is here:

```
sheet.addRule("table.inner {width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: #F2F2F2; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: #666666;}");
```

```
sheet.addRule("table.outer {width: 100%; height: 100%; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: #666666;}");
```

```
sheet.addRule("div {padding:5; height: 100%;}");
```

Basically, I get this:

```
=========   =========
|a      |   |a      |
|a      |   |a      |
|a      |   |a      |
|a      |   =========
=========
=========   =========
| .     |   |.      |
| .     |   |.      |
```

But I'd like this:

```
=========   =========
|a      |   |a      |
|a      |   |a      |
|a      |   |a      |
|a      |   |       |
=========   =========
=========   =========
| .     |   |.      |
| .     |   |.      |
```

This all  happens in a JEditorPane with an HTMLEditorKit applied to it, so I don't have any of the friendly features you might find in a browser.  Is there a way I can make my tables fill the remaining height?  I've tried dropp height:100% in most places but have had no luck.

Thanks for reading

Comment: If all your purpose is showing data kinda report to the user, try the `JTable` class. Here's a tutorial. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

Comment: Unfortunatly I need to do it using html, thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: the HTML support in Swing is quite restricted as you may have found out. If you have to this with pure HTML, this will painful. Another approach for you could be to use native Swing components and use the fact that JLabel can handle basic HTML. But without knowing your complete context, it is hard to say.

Comment: I'll post some of the html in the next comment - I can't fit all that much in so it's hard to show the context, but essentially I'm putting in one row of the outer table with two inner tables inside it, one of which has one row and one of which has two.  Rendering this code in a browser results in what I want automatically, but as @GuillaumePolet says, I think the JEditorPane is going to make this difficult.  If it has to be something a bit nasty/hacky then so be it.  I did try to mimick the behaviour I want by bordering the cells of the outer table but that didnt work either.

Comment: <tr>
   <td class="outer" valign = "top">
    <div>
     <table class="inner">
      <tr>
       <td colspan="2"><strong>heading</strong></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>heading:</td>
       <td>data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>heading:</td>
       <td>data</td>
      </tr>
     </table>
    </div>
   </td>
   <td class="outer" valign = "top">
    <div>
     <table class="inner">
      <tr>
       <td colspan="2"><strong>heading</strong></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td colspan="2">No Data Available</td>
      </tr>
     </table>
    </div>
   </td>
  </tr>